# unable to update existing json list using jsonconverter

Tags: c#, json.net, realm

i am trying to add field in json while deserializing the response from server and then storing it into database

here is the model of Response

```
 public class Response : RealmObject
    {

        [JsonConverter(typeof(QuotationConverter))]
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public IList<Quotation> quotationsList { get; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public IList<Order> ordersList { get; }
    }
```

QuotationConverter code where i am fetching customer name from another json and store it into quotation

```
 protected override IList<Quotation> parseArray(Type objectType, JArray jsonArray)
        {

            try
            {
                Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();
                foreach (JObject data in jsonArray)
                {

                    String customerId = data.GetValue("customerId").ToString();
                    Customer customer = realm.All<Customer>().Where(c => c.customerId == Java.Lang.Long.ParseLong(customerId)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (customer != null)
                    {
                        String customerName = customer.customerName;
                        data.Add("customerName", customerName);
                    }

                }

                realm.Dispose();
                var quotationsList = jsonArray.ToObject<IList<Quotation>>();

                List<Quotation> quotation = new List<Quotation>(quotationsList);

                return quotationsList;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(" exception "+e.StackTrace);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected override Quotation parseObject(Type objectType, JObject jsonObject)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

here is the JsonConverter

```
 public abstract class JsonConverter<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return (objectType == typeof(JsonConverter<T>));

        }

        protected abstract T parseObject(Type objectType, JObject jsonObject);

        protected abstract IList<T> parseArray(Type objectType, JArray jsonArray);
        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            try
            {              
               var jsonArray = JArray.Load(reader);
               var data=  parseArray(objectType, jsonArray);              
               return data;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            return null;

        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Mo " + value);


        }
    }

the issue is when i am getting Response object inside that quotationsList is coming blank.
```

Json received from server

```
quotationsList: [
  {
    "account": null,
    "contactId": 0,
    "currency": "USD",
    "customerId": 5637144583,
    "deliveryAddress": "19TH and Edwardsville RD (RT203)\nGranite City,IL62040\nUSA",
    "expiryDate": "2017-09-04",
    "followUpDate": "2017-09-01",
    "mQuotationId": null,
    "opportunityId": 0,
    "postedOn": null,
    "prospectId": 0,
    "quotationFor": null,
    "quotationId": 5637155076,
    "quotationName": "United States Steel",
    "quotationNumber": "UST1-000022",
    "quotationStatus": "Confirmed",
    "requestReceiptDate": "2017-08-05",
    "requestShipDate": "2017-08-05",
    "siteId": "GLEN1",
    "wareHouseId": "37"
  }
```

expected json

```
quotationsList: [
  {
    "account": null,
    "contactId": 0,
    "currency": "USD",
    "customerId": 5637144583,
    "deliveryAddress": "19TH and Edwardsville RD (RT203)\nGranite City,IL62040\nUSA",
    "expiryDate": "2017-09-04",
    "followUpDate": "2017-09-01",
    "mQuotationId": null,
    "opportunityId": 0,
    "postedOn": null,
    "prospectId": 0,
    "quotationFor": null,
    "quotationId": 5637155076,
    "quotationName": "United States Steel",
    "quotationNumber": "UST1-000022",
    "quotationStatus": "Confirmed",
    "requestReceiptDate": "2017-08-05",
    "requestShipDate": "2017-08-05",
    "siteId": "GLEN1",
    "wareHouseId": "37",
    "customerName":"Jhon Caro"
  }
```

Quotation model

```
 public class Quotation : RealmObject , IMaster, IMedia, IProduct
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public String mQuotationId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long quotationId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public String customerName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string quotationName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string quotationNumber{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string deliveryAddress { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string expiryDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string requestShipDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string requestReceiptDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long prospectId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string followUpDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long opportunityId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string postedOn { get; set; }



    }
```

updated

```
protected override IList<Quotation> parseArray(Type objectType, JArray jsonArray)
{

    try
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        var data = jsonArray.ToObject<IList<Quotation>>();
        List<Quotation> quotationList = new List<Quotation>(data);



        foreach (Quotation quotation in quotationList)
        {

            long customerId = quotation.customerId;
            Customer customer = realm.All<Customer>().Where(c => c.customerId == customerId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (customer != null)
            {
                String customerName = customer.customerName;
                quotation.customerName = customerName;
            }

        }

        realm.Dispose();


        return quotationList;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(" exception "+e.StackTrace);
    }

    return null;
}
```

[image]

this is how my deserialize get called

> Response responseData = await Task.Run(() =>
>   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content));

Comment: difference is at last field `customerName` , i am adding it as a new field

Comment: Can you talk us through why you do the code you way you do, rather than just setting the `customerName` property on the `Quotation` after this line `List<Quotation> quotation = new List<Quotation>(quotationsList);`?

Comment: `quotationsList` has so many records and i am adding `customerName` for all list items exist in `quotationsList` so once i get the quotationsList prepared i am creating a new List and sending it back

Comment: Sure, I get that. But you are getting JSON into `jsonArray`, fiddling with `jsonArray`, and then converting it to `List<Quotation>`. Have you tried getting JSON into `jsonArray`, converting it to `List<Quotation>` and then fiddling with `List<Quotation>` instead?

Comment: nope let me try that

Comment: i have tired the way you have suggested but still i am getting blank in model

Comment: 'Response.quotationList` gets blank thats wht i meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not the JSON Deserialize or the add to the json array, the issue it that you have no record coming from the DataBase.

You are using this:

```
 long customerId = quotation.customerId;
            Customer customer = realm.All<Customer>().Where(c => c.customerId == customerId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (customer != null)
            {
                String customerName = customer.customerName;
                quotation.customerName = customerName;
            }
```

**FirstOrDefault**  will expect zero or more items to be returned by a query but you only want to access the first item in your code (i.e. you are not sure if an item with a given key exists)

Change this to `First();` and see if it throws and exception, if it does then this is your issue and your:

```
realm.All<Customer>().Where(c => c.customerId == customerId)
```

is returning incorrect data.

Comment: i am just modifying one field i.e. customer name in quotation if customer name exists i will assign that to quotation's customer name other will it will remain as it is. so its not necessary that every customer id exists in customer table hence i have used first or default and when customer name is not exists it will take quotation's customer name as null  , i don't see anything is wrong with the code. i tried ur `First` and its generating exception as customer id is not exists in customer but as i said its not necessary

Comment: the question is what happens when you do have a value returned.

Comment: i tried your `First` too but same issue. when `ReadJson` returns data the variable that receives the data is blank always

Comment: try serializing the list into JSON: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quotationsList, Formatting.None)

Comment: i tried to write it in `QuotationConverter ` by changing return type of parseArray to string but still not working

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Response : RealmObject
{
    //JsonConverter attribute should be decorating 'Quotation' class
    //[JsonConverter(typeof(QuotationConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<Quotation> quotationsList { get; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<Order> ordersList { get; }
}
```

Comment: do you mean to say rather then `IList<Quotation>` i should use `Quotation` only ?

Comment: No i mean move your JsonConverter attribute to Quotation class

Answer (score 1):

I believe this method of your converter is incorrect

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return (objectType == typeof(JsonConverter<T>));
}
```

`objectType` in this case would be of type `IList<Quotation>` not `JsonConverter<IList<Quotation>>`. I believe this should read:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return (objectType == typeof(T));
}
```

edit: While I do believe this is incorrect I no longer believe it is the root cause of the problem. I have reproduced the problem exactly and the fix was to change this line.

```
public IList<Quotation> quotationsList { get; }
```

to

```
public IList<Quotation> quotationsList { get; set; }
```

JsonConvert needs a public setter in order to be able to assign values to properties.

I also changed this line

```
Response responseData = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content));
```

to

```
Response responseData = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content));
```

this tells DeserializeObject call which class to try and deserialize into.